# Return two screens back in dynpro sequence

Tags: abap, dynpro

I want to develop the following logic:

[image: PASS 2 SCREENS BACK]

The box "`DISPLAY ALV`" corresponds to the function module `REUSE_ALV_GRID_DISPLAY`.

With `LEAVE TO SCREEN 0` I can't pass directly to `DISPLAY ALV`. Is it possible?

Thank you.

Comment: what is 'display alv'? you are in screen300 and want to go back to screen100?

Comment: 'Display ALV' is simply using FM REUSE_ALV...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you cannot *return* to FM, as you intend to do, 'cause FM is a special callable unit and `LEAVE TO SCREEN` statement works **only for screens**. However, you can return to screen 100 which shows that ALV.

Consider following coding, for which you should have screens 100 and 300 with custom containers `100_CONT` and `300_CONT` on them.

**Screen 100 PBO**

```
MODULE pbo_100 OUTPUT.
  SET PF-STATUS 'YOUR_PF_STATUS'.
  IF custom_container1 IS INITIAL.

    SELECT *
      FROM mara AS m
      INTO TABLE gt_mara
      WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM vbrp WHERE matnr = m~matnr ).

    CREATE OBJECT custom_container1
      EXPORTING
        container_name = cont_on_main.

    CREATE OBJECT grid1
      EXPORTING
        i_parent = custom_container1.

    CALL METHOD grid1->set_table_for_first_display
      EXPORTING
        i_structure_name = 'mara'
        is_layout        = gs_layout
      CHANGING
        it_outtab        = gt_mara.

    CREATE OBJECT event_receiver.
    SET HANDLER event_receiver->handle_double_click FOR grid1.

  ENDIF.
ENDMODULE.                             " PBO_100  OUTPUT
```

**Screen 300 PBO**

```
MODULE pbo_0300 OUTPUT.
  IF custom_container2 IS INITIAL.
    CREATE OBJECT custom_container2
      EXPORTING
        container_name = cont_on_dialog.

    CREATE OBJECT grid2
      EXPORTING
        i_parent = custom_container2.

    gs_layout-grid_title = 'Orders'.

    CALL METHOD grid2->set_table_for_first_display
      EXPORTING
        i_structure_name = 'VBRP'
        is_layout        = gs_layout
      CHANGING
        it_outtab        = gt_vbrp.

  ELSE.
    CALL METHOD grid2->refresh_table_display.
  ENDIF.

ENDMODULE.                             " PBO_0300  OUTPUT
```

**Screen 300 PAI**

```
MODULE pai_0300 INPUT.
  CASE ok_code.
    WHEN 'RETURN'.
      DATA: ans.
      CALL FUNCTION 'POPUP_TO_CONFIRM'
        EXPORTING
          titlebar              = 'SO sample'
          text_question         = 'Select next action'
          text_button_1         = 'Yes'
          icon_button_1         = 'ICON_CHECKED'
          text_button_2         = 'No'
          icon_button_2         = 'ICON_CANCEL'
          display_cancel_button = ' '
        IMPORTING
          answer                = ans.

      CASE ans.
        WHEN 1.
          LEAVE TO SCREEN 0.
        WHEN 2.
          LEAVE PROGRAM.
        WHEN OTHERS.
      ENDCASE.

  ENDCASE.
  CLEAR ok_code.
ENDMODULE.
```

**Main program**

```
CLASS lcl_event_receiver DEFINITION DEFERRED.

DATA: ok_code           LIKE sy-ucomm,
      gt_mara           TYPE TABLE OF mara,
      gt_vbrp           TYPE TABLE OF vbrp,
      grid1             TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid,
      grid2             TYPE REF TO cl_gui_alv_grid,
      cont_on_main      TYPE scrfname VALUE '100_CONT',
      cont_on_dialog    TYPE scrfname VALUE '300_CONT',
      custom_container1 TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container,
      custom_container2 TYPE REF TO cl_gui_custom_container,
      event_receiver    TYPE REF TO lcl_event_receiver.

START-OF-SELECTION.

  CALL SCREEN 100.

CLASS lcl_event_receiver DEFINITION.
  PUBLIC SECTION.
    METHODS: handle_double_click FOR EVENT double_click OF cl_gui_alv_grid
      IMPORTING e_row e_column.
ENDCLASS.

CLASS lcl_event_receiver IMPLEMENTATION.
  METHOD handle_double_click.
    READ TABLE gt_mara INDEX e_row-index ASSIGNING FIELD-SYMBOL(<fs_mara>).

    SELECT *
      INTO TABLE gt_vbrp
      FROM vbrp
      WHERE matnr = <fs_mara>-matnr.

    CALL SCREEN 300 STARTING AT 10 5.
  ENDMETHOD.

ENDCLASS.
```

Here at program start we fetch material list with sales orders in the system, and then on double click on screen 100 these orders are showed in screen 300.

By special button with function code `RETURN` (you should place it on screen 300) we call popup window for interaction with user. By pressing **Yes** it returns to the initial screen 100, by pressing **No** the program is interrupted completely.

Here you should pay attention to statement `LEAVE TO SCREEN 0` which terminates current dynpro sequence (i.e. 300) and thus returns to 100.

Answer (score 0):

I can't say for sure if this will work but you should try 'set screen 0'.  I recently had to do this after programming a 'refresh' button into my ALV report, because after refreshing and re-displaying data, it took multiple 'green arrow' clicks to get out of the report.